# Why isn't a long/int available for use as a decimal (fraction)?

Tags: floating-point

In a previous project of mine (which I posted a question about here), I was very annoyed by the realization that I would have to deal with rounding errors in floating point numbers. The rounding error was an issue to me because I was doing collision detection, and allowing the rounding error to round up meant that I was allowing objects to collide. There are a couple solutions I see to this, but require guesswork type solutions.

A) One could ignore small collisions, but how do you know how small of a collision to expect? The nature of floating points makes rounding error/precision hard to predict, other than that you know the precision gets smaller for the fractional portion as the number gets farther from 0.

B) One could automatically subtract a small number to make sure floating point rounding errors generally don't cause issues. This solution has the same problem as the solution above.

I decided to go for solution B as it was easier to implement. I do admit that rounding error could be wrangled in somewhat by translating to local space before doing such calculations, but it doesn't feel like an elegant solution to me.

I then began to think about another solution, which has been culminating into a complete idea since then. Why aren't integers/longs used as fractions? The advantage this brings is that it would have predictable stepping and rounding error. An int can only go up or down by 1, so you would only ever have to worry about that kind of stepping. This also would make various behaviors more predictable in general. You wouldn't have to think of the type of input your code is receiving, as behavior wouldn't change as numbers get further from 0. Also, if I remember correctly from my limited research, floating points can take loads of CPU cycles, while I think ints don't have such issues.

Let me explain a little bit deeper what I mean...

0b00000000000000001111111111111111 represents a binary number that would usually be a 32 bit integer. But what if the 1's in that binary number represented the fractional portion of a number, so that 0b0000000000000000.1111111111111111 would represent a number very very close to 1. This scheme would give an unsigned short level of precision for the fractional part of the number, and a signed short level of precision for the whole part of the number (yeah, kinda low). If a long was used to represent the fractional number here, the precision on both sides would be integer level, which is often more than enough for most needs. The number of bits used to represent the fractional portion of the number could be variable as well, depending on what you need, aka 48 bits for the whole number and 16 bits for the fraction.

There probably could be a code implementation of this, but a hardware implementation would be cool and could be more efficient. The variable bits of precision for the fraction could be difficult, but the rest sounds very doable to me. Tell me if I am wrong on the assumptions I have made, and if there is a reason this doesn't exist already(or if it does, what is it called)? I can't be the first person to think of this. In case it wasn't obvious, I come

Comment: How accurate are the movements? Doubles allow a precision of up to 14-15 digits. Even with accumulating errors, I'd guess that is good enough for most purposes, even on a cosmic scale. Just be sure to make your computations thus that the errors don't pile up too much. FWIW, what you are describing is a (very limited) **fixed point format**. Has been done many times, but I guess that hardware supported **doubles** are **much faster, much more reliable and precise enough for most purposes, probably even for yours**. And they allow you to use sines and cosines and other trigonometic functions.

Comment: FWIW, there are no hardware implementations of your fixed point format that I know of, but if there are, they are probably not found on run-of-the-mill hardware.

Comment: FWIW, the fixed point format you describe has a very limited range (-32768..0..+32767 in steps of 0.0000152587890625) and note that any calculations (multiplication, division, trigonometric functions) would also require rounding, and the effects of that would be **much** worse than the effects of FP rounding (accuracy of 1/65536 only). I'd really advise you to use **double** and if you got that in place, try to change double for single/float and see if that is good enough too. You'll probably find out that it is much better than your limited fixed point type.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Thanks for the replies, I understand that if you used a 32 bit integer the range would be abysmal, but if you used a 64 bit integer there is quite a lot of range there, as I stated above in my wall of text. For what it is worth, I wanted to use doubles, but I've set my entire positioning system in that program to use 32 bit floats since I don't think OpenGL supports doubles, and I hate to cast from double to float every time I am dealing with OpenGL. I find floating point fractions to be quite limited, but doubles have so much more that it feels endless for many applications.

Comment: yes, the range would be a bit better, but you would still have the same problems. But hey, try it. Invent your own routines, do a lot of work and then compare it with hardware-supported double and you'll see you did a lot of work for nothing. Fixed point is fine, but very limited and you are on your own. Guess **why** there are no hardware versions of such a type. The idea is not new, after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is known as "fixed point", and it's used quite frequently. Some issues, though:

- It has a small range compared to floating point (duh).
- It isn't inherently more exact than floating point. If you used a fixed-point representation, 0.5 + 0.25 would exactly equal 0.75, but that would also be the case with floating point. A 32-bit floating point number wouldn't be able to accurately represent `10^10 - 1`, but neither would a 32-bit fixed point number (because it wouldn't be able to represent at least one of the values). Likewise, 1/3 wouldn't be any more exact in fixed point than it would in floating point.

Floating point error comes from gaps between floating point numbers, but fixed point numbers have gaps too, and the median gap between any two consecutive floating point numbers is roughly the same as the median gap between any two consecutive fixed point numbers (assuming that their median values are also roughly the same, which is the case in your example).

As for hardware implementations: You already have one! All arithmetic operations on fixed point types can be emulated straightforwardly with integers. (Indeed, addition and subtraction can be used without any changes.) Things like square roots and trigonometric functions get a little hairier, but as long as you have a floating point type with a mantissa big enough to store one of your fixed point numbers (e.g. a `double` to store a 32-bit fixed point number) you can leverage that hardware as well.

You also mentioned the use of variably sized types. Those can come in handy in certain cases, but they're not common: IME, required ranges for datatypes in numerical applications tend to be either "not that big" or "basically infinite". And you won't be able to store 1/3 no matter how big your fraction gets.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I did realize the setbacks pointed out above, but there are also times when these setbacks seem irrelevant compared to the advantages that fixed point could bring in certain scenarios. Another solution to my issue that I just thought of would be if there was a way to make rounding error always result in rounding down, for that specific calculation. A 64 bit fixed point number wouldn't have nearly the limitation that a 32 bit fixed point number would, as ~4 billion possible numbers for the fraction is quite a bit for most needs.

Comment: The advantages are only imagined. But try it. Do the work and compare. You'll be very disappointed. How do I know? Guess.